# How do I associate a Vagrant project directory with an existing VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Somehow my Vagrant project has disassociated itself from its VirtualBox VM, so that when I `vagrant up` Vagrant will import the base-box and create a new virtual machine.

Is there a way to re-associate the Vagrant project with the existing VM?
How does Vagrant internally associate a Vagrantfile with a VirtualBox VM directory?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**WARNING:** The solution below works for Vagrant 1.0.x but *not* Vagrant 1.1+.

Vagrant uses the ".vagrant" file in the same directory as your "Vagrantfile" to track the UUID of your VM. This file will not exist if a VM does not exist. The format of the file is JSON. It looks like this if a single VM exists:

```
{
   "active":{
      "default":"02f8b71c-75c6-4f33-a161-0f46a0665ab6"
   }
}
```

`default` is the name of the default virtual machine (if you're not using multi-VM setups).

If your VM has somehow become disassociated, what you can do is do `VBoxManage list vms` which will list every VM that VirtualBox knows about by its name and UUID. Then manually create a `.vagrant` file in the same directory as your `Vagrantfile` and fill in the contents properly.

Run `vagrant status` to ensure that Vagrant picked up the proper changes.

**Note:** This is not officially supported by Vagrant and Vagrant may change the format of `.vagrant` at any time. But this is valid as of Vagrant 0.9.7 and will be valid for Vagrant 1.0.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I had a feeling something was missing.

Comment: Could be 'default' changes to custom name without using multi-VM config?

Comment: For Vagrant 1.1, the UUIDs are stored in a machine-specific file at `.vagrant/machines/{name}/{provider}/id`. In fact, the only thing that file contains is the UUID.

Comment: I tried this trick but vagrant status simply reports the state as not created. Vagrant up then creates a new vm and works fine. If I change the id file it then reports as not created, even if I change it back to the uuid of the box it just created.

Comment: With Vagrant 1.1+, make sure you don't add a newline to the end of the id. See https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1755 for details

Comment: +1 to @JustinY - the `{provider}` specific directory structure was the key for me

Comment: I was looking for .vagrant in my profile (Mac).  Note that (at least for me) it was in the same folder as the cookbooks folder and VagrantFile. (Vagrant version 1.4.3)

Comment: @Mitchell, there is a popular plugin for Vagrant https://github.com/tknerr/vagrant-managed-servers which allows you to use existing virtual machine from many projects. For example, I develop on Windows/OSX, have one vagrant docker-host machine, and all my other projects just mapp some folders to docker-host, and start containers there. Unfortunately this plugin has some issues, in particular rsync/rsync-auto do not work with it. Why not to make this possibility integral part of Vagrant, so we don't have to hack .vagrant folders ?

Answer (score 223):

For **Vagrant 1.6.3** do the following:

1) In the directory where your Vagrantfile is located, run the command

```
VBoxManage list vms
```

You will have something like this:

```
"virtualMachine" {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

2) Go to the following path:

```
cd .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox
```

3) Create a file called **id** with the ID of your VM xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

4) Save the file and run **vagrant up**

Comment: A good way to create the `id` file *without* a newline is `echo -n '<your id here>' > id` .

Comment: Works great. But why does this happen?

Comment: Worked for me with Vagrant 1.7.2. Thanks!

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: # test1 and test2 boxes...
`for box in test1 test2; do virtualboxid=$(VBoxManage list vms | grep $box | cut -d' ' -f2); echo -n $virtualboxid > .vagrant/machines/$box/virtualbox/id; done`

Comment: When running `VBoxManage list vms` on Windows, if you get an error "VBoxManage: command not found", you can try this instead: `"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" list vms`

Comment: Works with Vagrant 2.x also. btw, if using Vim, be sure to `:set binary` and `:set noeol` so it won't add a newline at the end.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue too. I had a cluster so I just copied over all the machine directories in the `machines` directory.

Answer (score 48):

The solution with upper version is quite the same.

But first you need to launch the .vbox file by hand so that it appear in `VBoxManage list vms`

Then you can check the `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id` to check that the uuid is the right one.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that if you're editing the `id` file, you must keep it to a single line. For some reason it doesn't like newline at end (my text editor adds it by default, so I had problems).

Comment: I ran into an issue with this because I had renamed the folder that it was in.  Vagrant insisted on creating a new VM with the same name as the folder, instead of using the existing VM.  I fixed it by creating a `.vagrant` file in the 1.0 format, and it upgraded it automatically.  As soon as I did, it actually renamed the old VM to the new project directory name.

Comment: I am not sure what caused the disconnect where my vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id pointed to the wrong VirtualBox machine id.  The file which helped was $HOME/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml.  It has a MachineRegistry section having the VirtualBox machine UUIDs mapped to the machine names.  For instance <MachineEntry uuid="{f232f951-103b-af28-9f8d-b2ab21bs258f}" src="$HOME/VirtualBox VMs\<machine-name>\<machine-name>.vbox"/>

Answer (score 15):

Had the issue today, my `.vagrant` folder was missing and found that there was a few more steps than simply setting the id:

1. Set the id:

   ```
   VBoxManage list vms
   ```

   Find the id and set in `{project-folder}/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id`.

   Note that `default` may be different if set in your `Vagrantfile` e.g. `config.vm.define "someothername"`.
2. Stop the machine from provisioning:

   Create a file named `action_provision` in the same dir as the `id` file, set it's contents to: `1.5:{id}` replacing `{id}` with the id found in step 1.
3. Setup a new public/private key:

   Vagrant uses a private key stored in `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key` to ssh into the machine. You'll need to generate a new one.

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa
   ```

   name it `private_key`.

   `vagrant ssh` then copy the `private_key.pub` into `/home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: is "authorized_keys" a file or directory?

Comment: it's a file, if you search on it you'll find plenty of stuff, it's a standard ssh thing

Comment: Because I was using the same keys, I didn't have to do the last setp (third). Otherwise, really well explained and everything perfect.

Comment: How to do the third step on win10？

Answer (score 9):

Update with same problem today with Vagrant 1.7.4:

- useful thread at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1755
  and specially with following commands:

For example, to pair box 'vip-quickstart_default_1431365185830_12124' to vagrant.

```
$ VBoxManage list
"vip-quickstart_default_1431365185830_12124" {50feafd3-74cd-40b5-a170-3c976348de27}
$ echo -n "50feafd3-74cd-40b5-a170-3c976348de27" > .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id
```

Answer (score 6):

For multi-VM setups, it would look like this:

```
{
   "active":{
        "web":"a1fc9ae4-5d43-49cb-be31-ab3c4f74745d",
        "db":"13503bc5-76b8-4c26-95c4-32435b372212"
   }
}
```

You can get the vm names from the Vagrantfile used to create those VMs.  Look for this line:

```
config.vm.define :web do |web_config|
```

"web" is the name of the vm in this case.

Comment: And **db** is a default VM ??

Comment: I don't think there is a default here, just web and db.  Depending on the Vagrantfile,  there is an order of which vm gets built first.

Answer (score 6):

This is modified from [@Petecoop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39742862/632786).

Run `vagrant halt` if you haven't shut down the box yet.

Then list your virtualboxes: `VBoxManage list vms`

It'll list all of your virtualboxes. Identify the box you want to revert to and grab the id between the curly brackets: `{}`.

Then edit the project id file: `sudo nano .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id` (from the project directory)

Replace it with the id you copied from the list of VBs.

Try `vagrant reload`.

**If that doesn't work and gets hung on SSH authorization** (where I stumbled), copy the insecure public key from the [vagrant git](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/keys/vagrant). Replace the content of `/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key`. Backup the original of course: `cp private_key private_key-bak`.

Then run `vagrant reload`. It'll say it's identified the insecure key and create a new one.

```
default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
```

You should be all set.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using **Vagrant 1.8.1** on **OSX El Capitan**

My vm was not shut correctly when my computer restarted, so when i tried `vagrant up` it was always creating new vm. No solutions here worked for me. But what did work was a variation of [ingmmurillo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434313/how-do-i-associate-a-vagrant-project-directory-with-an-existing-virtualbox-vm#25516777)

So instead of creating `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id` based on the id from running `VBoxManage list vms`. I had to update the id in `.vagrant/machines/local/virtual_box/id`

I've got a one liner that essentially does this for me:

`` echo -n `VBoxManage list vms | head -n 1 | awk '{print substr($2, 2, length($2)-2)}'` > .vagrant/machines/local/virtualbox/id ``

This assumes the first box is the one i need to start from running `VBoxManage list vms`

Answer (score 3):

In Vagrant 1.9.1:

I had a VM in Virtual Box named 'Ubuntu 16.04.1' so I packaged it as a vagrant box with:

```
vagrant package --base "Ubuntu 16.04.1"
```

responds with...

```
==> Ubuntu 16.04.1: Exporting VM...
==> Ubuntu 16.04.1: Compressing package to: blah blah/package.box
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on macos and found that removing the .locks on the boxes solved my problem.

For some reason

```
vagrant halt
```

did not remove these locks, and after restoring all my settings in .vagrant/machine/default/virtualbox using timemachine, removing the locks, the right machine booted up.

Only 1 minor problem remains, It booted into grub so I had to press enter once, don't know if this is staying, but I will find out soon enough.

I'm running vagrant 1.7.4 and virtualbox 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

for me deleting the

```
cd yourVagrantProject/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/
rm id
```

worked.