# vagrant up is not starting the vm in .vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\id

Tags: vagrant

When I run vagrant up, a new virtualbox machine is created rather than running the virtualmachine identified in `.vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\id`.  The id of the new virtual machine is then written to the `id` file.

My VMs:

```
C:\Users\Chris>vboxmanage  list vms
"MyVM_1373377014" {177aef6c-b9ec-4a85-adad-76c70f80fa62}
```

Next:

`C:\Users\Chris>echo 177aef6c-b9ec-4a85-adad-76c70f80fa62 > .vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\id`

Followed by:

`C:\Users\Chris>vagrant up`

Results in a new VM:

```
C:\Users\Chris>vboxmanage  list vms
"MyVM_1373377014" {177aef6c-b9ec-4a85-adad-76c70f80fa62}
"MyVM_1373566342" {4fedb342-cc0b-40fd-a8d1-403049065274}
```

And the `id` containing the new VM id:

```
C:\Users\Chris>type .vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\id
4fedb342-cc0b-40fd-a8d1-403049065274
```

So a new VM is created for some reason rather than starting the existing one.

I'm running Vagrant version 1.2.3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure a newline isn't added to the ID.  Therefore, instead of this:

`echo "177aef6c-b9ec-4a85-adad-76c70f80fa62" > .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id`

I had to do this:

`echo -n "177aef6c-b9ec-4a85-adad-76c70f80fa62" > .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id`

Note the **-n** switch to the echo command.

Sources:

- https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1755
- [How do I associate a Vagrant project directory with an existing VirtualBox VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434313/how-do-i-associate-a-vagrant-project-directory-with-an-existing-virtualbox-vm)