# Can I add (create) shared directories from the host to a running Vagrant box on the fly?

Tags: share, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a situation where I would like to add shared folders to a running **Vagrant** box (Ubuntu guest) provided by **VirtualBox**.

[According to the docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html), these *"Synced Folders"* should be defined in the configuration file like so:

`config.vm.synced_folder "/mnt/plugdrive15", "/synced/plugdrive15"`

But what if I need to share directories that are new on my host? I have this often and I cannot predict their names, so I cannot pre-write them beforehand in the configuration file. I want to automate this.

Using `VBoxManage sharedfolder add` doesn't work, because as soon as you do `vagrant up`, only the shares specified in the configuration file (and the default `vagrant` one) are left.

If all else fails (no better solutions), can `Vagrantfile` parse a configuration file (in which I specify shares right before `vagrant up`?

Comment: you could just share the parent directory?

Comment: The parent is different on different platforms (and I don't want to have users share a folder close to root).

Answer (score 1):

You can using virtual box interface, you have a shared folder option in the VM setting and you can add a new folder while the VM is running

[**edit**]
there is ofc a command line tool associated : http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

[**edit 2**]
Setting the vm name is a provider specific operation, so VBoxManage tool will consider it as well.

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.name = "barhost"
end
```

If you don't specify a name vagrant will generated one, see [How to change Vagrant 'default' machine name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845637/vagrant-default-name) for precisions.

Comment: I know I can add one in the interface for the VM provider itself, but I'm looking for a Vagrant specific method, or otherwise platform independent command line trick.

Comment: Thanks, your edit is relevant to my question. I will try it out when I am back at the office. But how do I know the VM name when a client or script just does `vagrant up`? Is it a random name? Is it even managable by `VBoxManage` when it's set up by Vagrant?

Comment: This is not working. `Vagrant up` will remove any manually specified shares.

Comment: @edit2: I know, it's not the problem. Open the GUI. Add shared folders using `VBoxManage`. You see the shared folder counter in the GUI increase. Do `vagrant up`. You'll see the shared folder counter in the `GUI` reset to the number of shares specified in `Vagrantfile`. They won't stick.