# Set host name for Vagrant VM in Ansible

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

For testing Ansible, I've set up a Vagrant VM which can be provisioned with `vagrant provision`, given

```
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
end
```

in the `Vagrantfile`. This works when I set `hosts` to `all`,

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: true
  roles:
    - common
    - ssl
    - webserver
```

Alternatively, the file

```
.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory
```

which is generated by Vagrant itself says

```
default ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
```

meaning that the name of the Vagrant VM is `default`. Hence,

```
- hosts: default
```

also does what I want. However, I'd like to have a more specific name for the VM (like `vagrant`, for example).

Is there a way to change that name to something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to *define* the VM (here with 2 VMs `production` and `staging`):

```
config.vm.define "production" do |production|
  production.vm.hostname = "production.example.com"
end

config.vm.define "staging" do |staging|
  staging.vm.hostname = "staging.example.com"
end
```

Then vagrant generates the following inventory:

```
production ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
staging ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20431791).

Answer (score 5):

To change *only the inventory hostname* in `.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory`, use:

```
config.vm.define "myvm"
```

This will generate the following:

```
# Generated by Vagrant
myvm ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
```

Thus, ansible `inventory_hostname` will become `myvm`.

If you want to **also** change the hostname of the machine, use:

```
config.vm.define "myvm" do |myvm|
  myvm.vm.hostname = "myvm.example.com"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read [The inventory file](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_intro.html#the-inventory-file) from the vagrant doc

If you want to change the name of the VM, you could have something like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "host1"
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
```

which will produce the inventory file

```
# Generated by Vagrant

host1 ansible_ssh_host=...
```

Note that vagrant also proposed a [static inventory](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_intro.html#static-inventory) option which will allow you to write your own inventory file and reference with the [`inventory_path`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#inventory_path) option

Comment: This only only changes the `hostname` within the VM, not the contents of `.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory` and hence not the name Ansible refers to.