# Vagrant config terminology

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

TL;DR; Can someone help me understand the difference between these "names" defined in a Vagrantfile?

1. `config.vm.define "worker"`
2. `box.vm.box = "ots-box"`
3. `box.vm.host_name = "worker"`
4. `vb.name = "barhost"`

---

While trying to change the hostname of the vagrant instance I had, I was lost in the Vagrantfile syntax. Now I have successfully changed the hostname but some other things (network) isn't working. I suspect I've changed something that has lead vagrant to configure the box is a particular way, which caused this issue.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "worker".to_sym do |box|
    box.vm.box = "ots-box"
    box.vm.box_url = "http://testing.xxx.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ots-fe.box"
    box.vm.host_name = "worker"
end
```

I suppose it's irrelevant but I'm trying to create an ubuntu box on Mac El-capitan with Oracle VirtualBox and vagrant version 1.7.4.

---

[Documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html) says:
config.vm.box - This configures what box the machine will be brought up against. The value here should be the name of an installed box or a shorthand name of a box in HashiCorp's Atlas.

[Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20431791/496289) introduces another term `vb.name`:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
  config.vm.define "foohost" do |foohost|
  end
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.name = "barhost"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to answer points by points:

First the following syntax

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|   
  config.vm.define "worker".to_sym do |box|
    box.vm.box = "ots-box"
    box.vm.box_url = "http://testing.xxx.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ots-fe.box"
    box.vm.host_name = "worker" 
  end
```

is mainly used if you have multiple VMs running (https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/) so you need to define a name for the VM, in your case `worker` so within the next block all the parameters will be set for the `worker` VM and to make ruby syntax happy you need to define a variable name (`box`)

so if you have a single VM within your Vagrantfile, you do not need this syntax, you can just have

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|   
    config.vm.box = "ots-box"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://testing.xxx.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ots-fe.box"
    config.vm.hostname = "worker" 
  end
```

Second, the `config/box.vm.box` points to a [vagrant box](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes.html) This is a very important concept of Vagrant as each VM you will spin must be created against an existing box. You can download box from internet (vagrant atlas, http://www.vagrantbox.es/) or make the box yourself. You can review the available boxes installed on your machine by running `vagrant box list`. If the box set in your Vagrantfile is not available in the available box, vagrant will try to download (so if you point something like `ubuntu/trusty64`, even if you did not install it, vagrant will download it from https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64, assuming it is available for your provider)

Third, the `config/box.vm.hostname` will be the variable you're interested (not hostname vs host_name), from the [doc](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html)

> config.vm.hostname - The hostname the machine should have. Defaults to
>   nil. If nil, Vagrant won't manage the hostname. If set to a string,
>   the hostname will be set on boot.

so if you set this variable in your Vagrantfile and boot the machine, the `hostname` variable in ubuntu will be resolved to this same value. As an example, from the following Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.hostname = "ubuntu"
  ...
```

from the vm, I get

```
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/ubuntu$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-virtual x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Tue Jan  5 10:21:54 2016 from 172.16.42.1
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ hostname
ubuntu
```

Finally the *name* topic, `config/box.vm.name` will be used for the name of the VM from the provider (in your case VirtualBox), it is quite well explained from the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20431791/4296747)

Comment: Thanks for the great writeup! So the last one (`vb.name`) is just a name for the provider GUI, right? In my case name as it appears in the Oracle VirtualBox GUI.

Comment: yes you can set the name so that it appears meaningful