# VirtualBox using Vagrantfile and Ansible: VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete

Tags: vagrant, ansible, windows-10, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'd like to run VirtualBox using Vagrantfile and Ansible.

In first place I turn on virtualization in my BIOS:

[image]

And turn on Linux subsystem on Windows.

Then I work on Bash on Windows.

I install VirtualBox:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Then I install Vagrant:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vagrant
```

And then I install Ansible:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properities-common
sudo apt-get-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ansible
```

I have Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

IP = "192.168.33.55"

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64" #target OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

  config.ssh.username = "ubuntu"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|

    v.name = "jenkins"

    v.memory = 1024

    v.cpus = 2

    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]

    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--ioapic", "on"]

  end

  config.vm.hostname = "jenkins"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.55"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Set the name of the VM. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17864388/100134

  config.vm.define :jenkins do |jenkins|

  end

  # Ansible provisioner.

      config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|

     ansible.playbook = "jenkins/playbook.yml"

     ansible.inventory_path = "jenkins/inventory"

     ansible.sudo = true

  end

end
```

So, I try to run it

```
vagrant up
```

But I have an error:

```
VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error
```

Of course, I check:

```
VBoxManage --version
```

And I see:

```
The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist. Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate headers, most likely linux-headers-3.4.0+. You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed
```

When I try to install it

```
 apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

It says that the latest version is installed yet.

Also I tried:

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
```

Successfull, but error is still here

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Successfull, but error is still here

My CPU isn't support Secure Boot in BIOS.

I have Windows 10 Professional.

My hardware:
Dual Core AMD Athlon II X2 250, 3000 MHz
Asus M5A78L-M LX3
16 Gb DRAM

So, how can I run my Vagrantfile? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the next (and final) step is to compile the kernel module for vbox, but I don't remember what command that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think VirtualBox can run on Windows Linux subsystem: [Unable to install VirtualBox in Windows Bash - Ubuntu (Windows 10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816343/unable-to-install-virtualbox-in-windows-bash-ubuntu-windows-10)

Consider installing VirtualBox on Windows itself.