# How do you set the VM name via Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant

I've set up 4 VMs in Vagrant and now trying to set the name of a VM in Vagrant as I don't just want to ssh into the default VM.

I can't find any docs on the vagrant website but found this:

[How to change Vagrant 'default' machine name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845637/how-to-change-vagrant-default-machine-name)

However, when I try:

`config.vm.define "foohost"`

and do a `vagrant up` I get:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: define
```

Comment: The answer you are linking to is correct. Are you adding only the line with `define` or also the lines around it, as explained in the linked answer ? If you don't show all the code, we cannot help. Are you familiar with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you actually wrote

> config.vm.define = "foohost"

rather than

> config.vm.define "foohost"

as that would explain the error message. (Best to show several lines of actual source if you can.)

Answer (score 0):

> as I don't just want to ssh into the default VM.

so when you use multiple VM, you can tell vagrant which VM you want to ssh by default, using the following

```
config.vm.define "foohost", primary: true do |foohost|
    ...
end
```

then when you run `vagrant ssh` you will ssh by default in this VM.
To ssh into the other MV, you will need to specify the VM name