# Is there any way to clone a vagrant box that is already installed

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I must have the same VM in other computers but I don't want to download the whole box, php mysql, etc...

I have a box already configured the way it should be and I want to run this VM in others computers.

When the user run "vagrant up" the machine should start without downloading nothing.

Does anybody have a solution for that?

Comment: I wrote some scripts for automating the transfer of vagrant boxes. See [soniah/transfer_vagrant_boxes](https://github.com/soniah/transfer_vagrant_boxes)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to [package the pre-configured vagrant box](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html) and transfer the .box file to the other machine, add the box and run `vagrant up`.

So the steps look like below:

1. Package the pre-configured box => `vagrant package --base preconfigured_vm --output /path/to/mybox.box`. **Note** that as per the docs, the `--base` option should be the UUID of the machine, or the name VirtualBox gives the machine (found when opening the VirtualBox application).
2. transfer the box to the computer by using `scp`, `rsync` or whatever... (you also start a web server quickly by using `python -m http.server PORT` or `ruby -run -e httpd /path/to -p PORT`)
3. Init and start `vagrant init preconfigured_vm /path/to/mybox.box`
4. Done

Comment: To pass in the UUID of the preconfigured_vm to the --base parameter in Vagrant 1.1+, I followed the [tip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434313/how-do-i-associate-a-vagrant-project-directory-with-an-existing-virtualbox-vm#comment23660947_9437813):  "For Vagrant 1.1, the UUIDs are stored in a machine-specific file at .vagrant/machines/{name}/{provider}/id. In fact, the only thing that file contains is the UUID."

Comment: If you're using VirtualBox, you can also get the UUID/name from the command `VBoxManage list vms`.

Comment: Also, to add the box you can run the command `vagrant box add --name="boxname" mybox.box` where the `name` is the value from your Vagrant file's `config.vm.box` property and `mybox.box` is the box created from step 1 in Terry's answer.

Comment: Also, send the other user your Vagrantfile too, as this stores important details for vagrant to use when spinning up a new box.

Comment: Good instructions, but results in a large file.  Try using `dd` to wipe any blank space, as suggested here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-a-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-one

The difference for me was 3.1GB vs 2.2GB.

Answer (score 6):

You just have to download the VM box only one time and make the all changes and configurations that you need and then re-package this one on a new box called "myVM.box".

Then you comment in the Vagrantfile the following line

```
#config.vm.box_url = "https://site_of_boxes..."
```

and used

```
config.vm.box = "myVM"
```

It starts up without download any VM.