# Vagrant never finishes `up`

Tags: linux, centos, vagrant, system-administration

I'm attempting to package an existing VirtualBox VM for our dev team to easily distribute and use. Given the box is already set up, I installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

The problem is that after I package the box and `add` it to Vagrant, I run `vagrant up` and everything seems to work fine, until it gets to:

```
  ==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/alex/vagrant/centos7
```

At this point, it just hangs. No issue. It didn't give any errors when `checking for guest additions in VM` either.

Also, if I add any network config to my Vagrantfile (`config.vm.network "public_network"`) it will hang at this point instead (`==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...`)

Really no idea where to go from here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: either turn on the GUI to check when it hangs or start with `vagrant up --debug` to get more information/log about the error

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if the guest addition version is different on the host and the vm. At this point, the folders may not be mounted but your vm should be up. Use `<Ctrl + C>` to come out of the script execution and then do `vagrant ssh`. Please make sure to install the correct guest additions version in the box and repackage.

Comment: I know I am able to `vagrant ssh` into the box. What is the best way to check the versions? Check the VBoxGuestAdditions ISO version and the VirtualBox software version?

EDIT: I have checked the versions, my VirtualBox and VBoxGuestAdditions ISO is the same version. 5.0.14.

Comment: Guest additions are installed in /opt. If that doesn't match, you need to mount the iso and reinstall and make sure to delete the older ones, if any. Also see if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717428/vagrant-error-failed-to-mount-folders-in-linux-guest/35737634#35737634