# Vagrant multiple identical boxes?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have two projects that use the `hashicorp/precise64` but they are completely different. How do I have multiple VMs of the `hashicorp/precise64` box?

I tried creating a separate project folder with `hashicorp/precise64` but it doesn't work as expected because the other project is using `hashicorp/precise64`. The error I get when I try `vagrant up` for this kind of setup is below:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise64'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/home/USER/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise64/1.1.0/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "precise64_1396016609451_23118", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "9", "--disk", "/home/USER/VirtualBox VMs/precise64_1396016609451_23118/box-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /home/USER/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise64/1.1.0/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Could not open the medium storage unit '/home/USER/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise64/1.1.0/virtualbox/box-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file '/home/USER/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise64/1.1.0/virtualbox/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Appliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 781 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followed the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094024/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-vagrant-box-that-is-already-installed):

What I did was:

1. `vagrant package` in the main projects location.
2. Moved the `package.box` to the new project location.
3. `vagrant init new_project_name ./package.box`
4. `vagrant up`