# how to access copied vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

**context:** I've been using a box previously made by someone else. I've been using vagrant up for that and it has been working out. I don't really understand vagrant and/or virtualbox.
**problem:** I deleted some files I want to use again.
**question:** I have made a copy of the box as soon as I started working and now I want to access that one with vagrant up. Is there a way to link that copied box to a folder (even if it's the old one)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about the [vagrant box](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes.html) or the generated VM ?

Comment: what's a generated vm?

Comment: the VM in VirtualBox. vagrant has the box which is in `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/<name_of_the_box` and the VirtualBox which is located (generally) under the VirtualBox folder

Comment: well I want to access a copy of the VM. I made a copy of it on VirtualBox, it's called <name_of_the_box> Clone

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434313/how-do-i-associate-a-vagrant-project-directory-with-an-existing-virtualbox-vm/25516777#25516777